# React Framer Motion animate only when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a dropdown menu and when it is toggled, the menu fades in and out. The thing I am trying to remove is the closing animation being activated when the initial page is loaded. I don't want the closed animation to play when the page is initially loaded.

```
const [menuOpen, setMenu] = useState(false);

const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  setMenu(false);
}, [location]);

const variants = {
  open: { opacity: 1, x: 0 },
  closed: { opacity: 0, x: "-25%" },
};

return (
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setMenu((menuOpen) => !menuOpen);
      }}
    >
    </button>
    <div>
      <motion.nav animate={menuOpen ? "open" : "closed"} variants={variants}>
        <DropDownMenu />
      </motion.nav>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Are there any solutions so that the animations only activate when the button is toggled?

Comment: could you try to pass `initial={false}` to the nav tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/component/###initial)

> Set to `false` to **initialise** with the values in animate (disabling the mount animation).

```js
// As false (disable mount animation)
<motion.div initial={false} animate={{ opacity: 0 }} />
```

So pass `initial={false}` to your `motion.nav` tag.